# How to build GWT standalone offline application?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, gwt, singlepage

I need to design SPA with GWT technology, but I do not understand clearly how to make (compile) only one page with all JavaScript code in it.

So, for example my task is to make simple page with button and div. You click on button and div appears on page. Simple. 
When I did this on GWT, I can not find a way to compile this page in simple index.html with all JS code inside (or in one .js file). Page should work in **offline** mode.

Comment: Actually yes, but I had no task to make a downloadable offline version of compiled HTML.

Answer (score 2):

GWT do it for you. compile it to one .js file?

Here is simple tutorial http://code.google.com/intl/en/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/gettingstarted.html

If you have any other question, please ask

and have a look at this.allyou need is here

http://www.vogella.de/articles/GWT/article.html

Answer (score 2):

Try Gears with GWT from google here the specs: 
http://www.slideshare.net/tom.peck/going-offline-with-gears-and-gwt